Curl POST both text message and file content
Due to this error in Postman, how can I POST a string message and file content on Ubuntu using curl in BASH shell? The body:
{
    "prompt": "Describe the type of shoe in the following image"
}

I tried
$ curl --insecure -X POST -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' https://localhost:4433/api/gemini -F "prompt=Describe the type of shoe in the following picture" -F "image=@/path/Shoe.jpg"
{"message":"Calling /api/gemini invalid prompt!"}

It doesn't get the "prompt" variable.
Using -d "prompt=message" works but this doesn't allow me to POST the image file.
